# How to view Facebook Pixel event parameters for standard and custom events in the overview page?

Tags: facebook-pixel, facebook-conversions-api

I have been using Facebook Pixel to track my website events using the Conversions API and sending a server event manually. I have used events with custom names and also standard events like "Purchase" before.

What I have not been able to do is viewing the event parameters.

For example, when I send the "Purchase" event using Postman to send a POST request to the endpoint like so:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/<PIXEL_ID>/events?access_token=<CONVERSIONS_API_ACCESS_TOKEN>`

The POST request body is as follow

```
{
    "test_event_code": "TEST33583",
    "data": [
        {
            "event_name": "OPL Click",
            "event_time": 1690724730,
            "action_source": "website",
            "user_data": {
                "external_id": [
                    "33b8f8b0775cb66001fb682da0ca40c204019491e6a8cd3217cd203d32c48e2b"
                ]
            },
            "custom_data": {
                "content_category": "Test section name",
                "content_name": "Test content name"
            },
            "data_processing_options_country": 0,
            "data_processing_options_state": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

The request is successful and the Test Event page in Events Manager shows like so:
[image]

This lead me to believe that the Events Manager can actually detect my custom parameters and record it. However, the Overview page doesn't seem to display them, and I can't find any part of the UI where the parameters should have been displayed except here.

[image]

I expanded the section where my "OPL Click" event was reorded, but the UI says that "No event parameters were detected" despite having shown them in the "Test Event" page?

Where exactly are the parameters recorded and can be viewed in the UI? Or is that feature even available in Facebook Events Manager at all? Thank you in advance for you help!

Answer (score 0):

it can be a bit challenging to find custom parameters for events sent through the Conversions API. Even if you've sent events with custom details and seen them in the Test Event page, locating these specifics in the main interface, such as the Overview page, isn't straightforward.

The thing is, the default view in Events Manager doesn't always display these custom parameters alongside your events. This can be frustrating because you'd expect to easily see them where you typically check your event data.

To get a clear view of these custom parameters, you might need to explore other options. Tools like the Facebook Pixel Helper or Event Debugging Tool can give insights into whether your events are firing correctly and what specific details are being sent.

Another way is to delve into custom conversion settings. Sometimes, these settings provide a more detailed breakdown of the parameters linked to your events.

If you need highly detailed data, using data exports or accessing raw event data through the API might be helpful. This could provide a more comprehensive understanding of the custom parameters associated with your events.

Basically, while it's a bit tricky to find these custom parameters directly in the Events Manager interface, there are other routes, like debugging tools, custom conversion settings, and raw data access, that can assist in uncovering and understanding these parameters better.

Comment: any affiliation with Facebook Pixel Helper? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: answer is not clear and if possible, provide sufficient supporting information or codes